# Add month/year to each returned row postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
select location,  subItem1, item2, SUM(sub.intervalEnd - sub.intervalStart +1) as days

from (select 
    location, item1,item2,
    case when effective_start_date> '2017-05-01' then effective_start_date else '2017-05-01' end as intervalStart,
    case when effective_end_date< '2017-05-31' then effective_end_date else '2017-05-31' end as intervalEnd,
    case when item1 =  'APPLE' then item1 else 'ORANGE' end as subItem1
from myTable

where (effective_start_date<='2017-05-01' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-01')
   OR (effective_start_date<='2017-05-31' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-31')
group by item1, item2, location, effective_start_date, effective_end_date
   )sub
  group by location, subItem1, item2
```

which returns a table like this:

```
Location | subItem1 | subItem2 | days
"LOC1","APPLE","thisItem2","31"
"LOC2","APPLE","thisItem2","31"
"LOC3","ORANGE","thisItem2","31"
"LOC4","APPLE","thisItem2","62"
"LOC5","APPLE","thisItem2","31"
"LOC6","APPLE","thisItem2","62"
```

But what I need is to add the Month/Year to each row like this:

```
"05/2017","LOC1","APPLE","thisItem2","31"
"05/2017","LOC2","APPLE","thisItem2","31"
"05/2017","LOC3","ORANGE","thisItem2","31"
"05/2017","LOC4","APPLE","thisItem2","62"
"05/2017","LOC5","APPLE","thisItem2","31"
"05/2017","LOC6","APPLE","thisItem2","62"
```

Any ideas?  I looked at the extract function but it only gives me either month or year.  But i need both.

Comment: @danihp Yeah I have been playing with that idea, the only problem is is it gives me extra rows for each location.  I can only have one row per location...

Answer (score -1):

Probably was a very noob question.  But I am only learning sql and managed to figure it out.   Answer was kind of easy really, just wrap it in another select statement.  Dunno if this is the best way to go about it - but it works:

```
select location,  subItem1, item2, days, theMonth

from (
select location,  subItem1, item2, SUM(sub.intervalEnd - sub.intervalStart +1) as days

from (select 
    location, item1,item2,
    case when effective_start_date> '2017-05-01' then effective_start_date else '2017-05-01' end as intervalStart,
    case when effective_end_date< '2017-05-31' then effective_end_date else '2017-05-31' end as intervalEnd,
    case when item1 =  'APPLE' then item1 else 'ORANGE' end as subItem1
from myTable

where (effective_start_date<='2017-05-01' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-01')
   OR (effective_start_date<='2017-05-31' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-31')
group by item1, item2, location, effective_start_date, effective_end_date
   )sub
  group by location, subItem1, item2

)t

group by location, month, item1, item2
order by location
```